# Does leaning whilst gliding reduce altitude?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I'm interested to know if using [Lean Techniques](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Lean_Techniques) whilst [Gliding](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Heart_of_Maguuma_mastery_tracks#Gliding) reduces your altitude quicker.

The documented effects are an increase in speed and faster depletion of your gliding endurance. However it stands to reason that if you're travelling faster your altitude would be reduced quicker as you're travelling further in a shorter time.

Is this assumption correct? If it is, in order to maximise lateral distance is it more beneficial to not lean forward?

Ref: [Glide ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gliding_flight#Glide_ratio)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leaning forward increases your glide ratio, meaning your forward speed increases, but you will still descend at the same rate as before. You can see this in game by looking at your character from the side while gliding. When leaning forward, the trail left by the glider is more flat compared to regular gliding:

[image: Gliding trail angles]

The [wiki page you linked](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Lean_Techniques) mentions that under notes:

> Leaning forward will reduce horizontal distance travelled for a given amount of endurance, but you will lose less vertical height than you would without leaning.

This means that when you want to reach a destination, such as a ledge across a ravine, leaning forward is *better*, because you lose less height overall. Of course, that is only if you can afford leaning forward in terms of gliding endurance (falling halfway is clearly not optimal).

In fact, there are several gliding "jumps" that are not possible without leaning forward all the way, for example the last glide to [Herta Tablet #12](http://dulfy.net/2015/10/29/gw2-a-study-in-gold-herta-tablets-achievements-guide/#12_Southgate_Youll_Only_Be_Able_to_Reach_This_from_Very_High_Up) in Auric Basin (see 5th image).

In short:

- Regular gliding allows you to go farther per endurance lost.
  You can go X units regularly, and Y < X with lean gliding before your gliding endurance is empty.
- Leaning forward allows you to go farther per height lost.
  You can go X units regularly, and Y > X with lean gliding before you lost 10 meters of height.

Here's some screenshots of a small test I did. I jumped from the position seen in image 1. Image 2 shows where I landed without leaning, image 3 shows the landing point when leaning forward all the way. I passed that big fern by a couple of meters while leaning.

[image: Starting point]
[image: Regular gliding end point]
[image: Lean gliding end point]

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the answer, any chance you can simplify it somehow? Clarification on horizontal distance vs altitude would be ideal. I think it's confusing having two comparisons which compare against different things.

Comment: @DavidYell I'll try and add a screenshot showing the difference in flying angle when I'm home, and maybe some in-game distance measurements, when I can find a nice spot to do those without being eaten by smokescales.

Comment: @DavidYell In short: Gliding doesn't follow real-world physics. Leaning makes you move sideways faster without going down faster. Leaning lets you get to higher spots, not leaning lets you go further.

Comment: Right, I think I get it. So I should be leaning all the time, unless I want to go for long distance.

Answer (score 3):

You fall at a steady rate while gliding, regardless of how you lean. Leaning forward will increase your horizontal movement speed (at the cost of endurance) and leaning backward will decrease your horizontal movement speed, but you will continue descending at a steady rate.